# (f)lex the difference between PRINTA$ and PRINT A$

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I am parsing BASIC:

```
530 FOR I=1 TO 9:C(I,1)=0:C(I,2)=0:NEXT I
```

The patterns that are used in this case are:

```
FOR  { return TOK_FOR; }
TO   { return TOK_TO; }
NEXT { return TOK_NEXT; }
(many lines later...)
[A-Za-z_@][A-Za-z0-9_]*[\$%\!#]? {
          yylval.s = g_string_new(yytext);
          return IDENTIFIER;
        }
(many lines later...)
[ \t\r\l]   { /* eat non-string whitespace */ }
```

The problem occurs when the spaces are removed, which was common in the era of 8k RAM. So the line that is actually found in *Super Star Trek* is:

```
530 FORI=1TO9:C(I,1)=0:C(I,2)=0:NEXTI
```

Now I know why this is happening: "FORI" is longer than "FOR", it's a valid IDENTIFIER in my pattern, so it matches IDENTIFIER.

The original rule in MS BASIC was that variable names could be only two characters, so there was no `*` so the match would fail. But this version is also supporting GW BASIC and Atari BASIC, which allow variables with long names. So "FORI" is a legal variable name in my scanner, so that matches as it is the longest hit.

Now when I [look at the manual](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html), and the only similar example deliberately returns an error. It seems what I need is "match the ID, but only if it's not the same as defined %token", is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to recognise keywords even if they have an identifier concatenated. What's tricky is deciding in what contexts you should apply that technique.

Here's a simple pattern for recognising keywords, using trailing context:

```
tail       [[:alnum:]]*[$%!#]?
%%
FOR/{tail}    { return TOK_FOR; }
TO/{tail}     { return TOK_TO; }
NEXT/{tail}   { return TOK_NEXT; }
  /* etc. */
[[:alpha:]]{tail}  { /* Handle an ID */ }
```

Effectively, that just extends the keyword match without extending the matched token.

But I doubt the problem is so simple. How should `FORFORTO` be tokenised, for example?

Comment: Wonderful answer as always rici! The trailing context is not something I have come across in any of the examples I read while looking at flex. I know that Atari would interpret that as FOR FORI, and then return and error for illegal ID. However, this project is only to run known-good programs, so this isn't an actual possibility. I'm not sure what GW will do, I'll try that.

Comment: Ahhh, there's the complexity you mentioned. For instance, the TO normally has a following number, not name. The Dragon Book addresses this through special code in their Java tokenizer that specifically rejects the "ID" pattern if it contains a keyword, which I think is what I'm needing here.

Comment: @maury: OK; I found the code you're talking about in a later edition. But you're misreading the code; it recognises a keyword if the *entire* token is a keyword (after "collect letters or digits into a buffer *b*", which is the token). The trailing context solution I propose does in fact recognised keywords at the start of what looks like an identifier, but I don't think it should be used in every context; I just don't know which contexts would be correct. It probably should only be used with keywords which could legally appear (so the second `FOR` in `FORFOR` is not a keyword)...

Comment: But that doesn't resolve the issue noted in the Dragon book (in a sidebar around section 3.1.3):  in Fortran, `DO5I=1.25` is an assignment, while `DO5I=1,25` is a loop starting with the keyword `DO`. A "tricky problem" indeed.